# Saving todo list items in the backend

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm having difficult coming up with the best possible way of storing todo list items in the backend. I was told that storing array and object in the backend was not a good idea. I'm trying to clone a google keep inspired web app.

Some context: as soon as the user submits their todo list, it will make an axios call to the backend that will iterate through an array of todo list items and save them individually to the backend.

Which inspired me with this current set up.

```
CREATE TABLE TODO (
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR,
user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(ID));



CREATE TABLE TODO_ITEM (
ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
item VARCHAR,
complete BOOLEAN,
todo_list_id INTEGER REFERENCES TODO(id));
```

My frontend call to the backend looks like this

```
 toDoArray.map(ele => { 
            axios.post('users/postToDoListItems', {
                item: ele, 
                complete: false,
                todo_list_id: ?

            })
        })
        axios.post('users/postToDoList', {
            title: title,
            toDoList: toDoList
        })
    }
```

The TODO_ITEM table I would like to to reference my TODO table so that when it's called to the frontend and grouped with the correct table. 
With my current setup, is it possible to pass the reference (TODO)ID to TODO_ITEM table?

Answer (score 0):

so aaaww i think you made some little mistakes i dont know how you query on your back-end but you must notice that before making your tables you must make a `connection` to your `db` soo i think it's not back to check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) 
or if you did it before plz complete your info about your problem , but the right thing for making queries is this :

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

and for query from front-end you should do this :

`<< fron-end >>`

```
 axios.post('users/postToDoListItems', {
                item: ele, 
                complete: false,
                todo_list_id: 1

            })
```

`<< back-end >>`

`route : postToDoListItems`

```
connection.query(`SET complete = ${req.body.complete} FROM todo WHERE id =${req.body.id}`, function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.json({results,fields})
    });
```